# fabric.js ascertain direction of object:moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs

I was wondering if there is a simple way of figuring out which direction an object on a fabric.Canvas was being dragged (up/down/left/right).

```
@me.on "object:moving", (e) =>
    # logic would presumably go here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many searches and trying to figure out ways of doing this, obviously, as soon as I post a question on the stack I figure out how to do it.

It seems that fabric uses [Pointer Lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Pointer_Lock). This means that you can do something like

```
var movX = e.movementX || e.mozMovementX || e.webkitMovementX || 0;
var movY = e.movementY || e.mozMovementY || e.webkitMovementY || 0;
```

positive numbers are right and down (respectively)
negative numbers are left and down (respectively)

Hope this helps somebody in the future